# Best R data structure to return table value counts

Tags: c++, sql, r, data-structures

The following function returns a data.frame with two columns:

```
fetch_count_by_day=function(con){
  q="SELECT t,count(*) AS count FROM data GROUP BY t"
  dbGetQuery(con,q)    #Returns a data frame
}
```

t is a DATE column, so output looks like:

```
       t       count(*)
1 2011-09-22     1438
...
```

All I'm really interested in is if any records for a given date already exist; but I will also use the count as a sanity check.

In C++ I'd return a `std::map<std::string,int>` or `std::unordered_map<std::string,int>` (*).
In PHP I'd use an associative array with the date as the key.

What is the best data structure in R? Is it a 2-column data.frame? My first thought was to turn the `t` column into rownames:

```
...
d=dbGetQuery(con,q)
rownames(d)=d[,1]
d$t=NULL
```

But data.frame rownames are not unique, so conceptually it does not quite fit. I'm also not sure if it makes using it any quicker.

(Any and all definitions of "best": quickest, least memory, code clarity, least surprise for experienced R developers, etc. Maybe there is one solution for all; if not then I'd like to understand the trade-offs and when to choose each alternative.)

*:  (for C++) If benchmarking showed this was a bottleneck, I might convert the datestamp to a YYYYMMDD integer and use `std::unordered_map<int,int>`; knowing the data only covers a few years I might even use a block of memory with one int per day between `min(t)` and `max(t)` (wrapping all that in a class).

Comment: What do you mean by "data.frame rownames are not unique"?  From ?rownames: " For a data frame, ‘value’ for ‘rownames’ should be a character vector of non-duplicated and non-missing names (this is enforced),"

Comment: What do you mean by "best"?  If it's speed of search then `data.table` might be a good idea.

Comment: @mdsumner I was going by the explanation and example here: http://www.r-bloggers.com/select-operations-on-r-data-frames/ But he is describing a matrix; are data frames different?

Comment: @gsk3 Any and all definitions of "best": quickest, least memory, code clarity, least surprise for experienced R developers, etc. Maybe there is one solution for all; if not then I'd like to understand the trade-offs and when to choose each alternative.

Comment: Can you add that answer to your question?

Answer (score 2):

Contingency tables are actually arrays (or matrices) and can very easily be created.The dimnames hold the values and the array/matrix at its "core" holds the count data. The "table" and "tapply" functions are natural creators. You access the counts with "[" and use dimnames( ) followed by an "[" to get you the row annd column names. I would say it was wiser to use the "Date" class for dates than storing in "character" vectors.

Comment: Hello @DWin, thanks for the answer and sorry for the delay in responding. In what ways is the R `table` type a better choice than alternatives (e.g. the data.frame, with the t column turned into rownmames)? And is there any way in which it is worse?